# Trying to enable client side validation in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, orchardcms, client-side-validation

I am trying to get client side validation enabled in Orchard for the comments. I have followed the advice in this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778897/is-it-possible-to-get-standard-asp-net-mvc-unobtrusive-validation-to-work-in-orc). I have commented out:

```
 //ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
 //ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider());
```

I have included the following in Resource Manifest in the Comments Module.

```
 manifest.DefineScript("jQueryValidation").SetUrl("jquery.validate.js", "jquery.validate.min.js").SetVersion("1.7").SetDependencies("jQuery");
        manifest.DefineScript("jQueryValidation_Unobtrusive").SetUrl("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js", "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js").SetDependencies("jQuery", "jQueryValidation");
```

I stuck the following inthe view:

```
this.Script.Require("jQueryValidation_Unobtrusive").AtHead();
```

Also I added DataAnnotation to the CommentPartRecord.cs file, decorating Author with [Required]

And the changes to the Web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

And despite all of this server side valdiation for the Comments is whjat works. There is no client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

The DataAnnotation should'nt be on CommentPartRecord but on CommentPart.

But Orchard.Comments is not a good example because CommentPart doesn't define the same properties than the Record (it will be refactored in a future version).

Try this on another module o one that you create.