# Orchard client-side validation - how SHOULD it look/work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm attempting to use client-side validation in an admin page in Orchard.  I've been successful at making it work using the techniques discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778897/is-it-possible-to-get-standard-asp-net-mvc-unobtrusive-validation-to-work-in-orc), but after doing some digging in the Orchard source and online, it seems to me that commenting out these lines

```
// Register localized data annotations    
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new LocalizedModelValidatorProvider());
```

is subverting some built-in Orchard functionality which allows for localized error strings.  At this point, either having these lines in our out of `OrchardStarter.cs` is the only difference between validation working and not working for me.

What I'm hoping for is some guidance on this, maybe from the Orchard team.  If these lines have to be out in order for validation to work, why are they there in the first place?  If they are there for a good reason, what am I (and others) doing wrong in our attempts to get client-side validation working?  I'm happy to post code samples if needs be, although it's a pretty standard ViewModel with data annotations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines are there to replace the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` (`DAMVP`) with Orchard's own implementation, which allows localizing the validation messages the Orchard way. The way it does this is by replacing e.g. `[Required]` with `[LocalizedRequired]` before passing control on to the `DAMVP`. Note that `DAMVP` *does* get to do its job - but only after Orchard has "messed" with the attributes.

The problem is that `DAMVP` uses the type of the `Attribute` to apply client validation attributes. And now it won't find e.g. `RequiredAttribute`, because it's been replaced by `LocalizedRequiredAttribute`. So it won't know what - if any - client validation attributes it should add.

So, out-commenting the lines will make you lose Orchard's localization. Leaving them in will make you lose client validation.

One workaround that *might* work (haven't looked enough through Orchard's code, and haven't the means to test at the moment) would be to make `DAMVP` aware of Orchard's `Localized` attributes and what to do with them.

`DAMVP` has a static [RegisterAdapter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidatorprovider.registeradapter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method for the purpose of adding new client rules for attributes. It takes the type of the attribute and the type of the Client-side adapter (the class that takes care of adding client attributes) to use.

So, something like the following might work:

In OrchardStarter.cs:

```
// Leave the LocalizedModelValidatorProvider lines uncommented/intact

// These are the four attributes Orchard replaces. Register the standard
// client adapters for them:

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(LocalizedRegularExpressionAttribute), 
    typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter)
);

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(LocalizedRequiredAttribute), 
    typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter)
);

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(LocalizedRangeAttribute), 
    typeof(RangeAttributeAdapter)
);

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(LocalizedStringLengthAttribute), 
    typeof(StringLengthAttributeAdapter)
);
```

As for the official word, it would seem this hasn't worked since localized validation was introduced in 1.3, and the impact is considered low: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18269

So, at the moment, it appears the official answer to the question title is, "it shouldn't".

Comment: Thanks, you've taken what I already knew/assumed about the situation and woven it together with what I didn't, and given me the answer I needed.  Much appreciated.